# Uploading file to dropbox (via syncing)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, synchronization, dropbox

Scenario:
I want to download a file to from DropBox account, and edit it in Offline ( i.e, without internet connection) mode, and when user comes back to Online mode, this file needs to be uploaded to Dropbox account.

Also

> I am done with downloading and uploading the file both.

Question:
But i want to know if their is any provision like, i can send an Intent to DropBox application and let the drop box do the uploading stuff. So that i will reduce my work to half.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the chooser for ACTION_SEND with

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("file/*"); 
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(filePath));  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Upload file");
```

Or explicitly get the Intent via `PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage()` for the Dropbox package `com.dropbox.android`.

Comment: Later solution seems to be valid for my scenario as i want Auto-save when user comes in Online mode. Could you please elaborate second solution. I think that would be helpful for me